# Sets, subset relations, and elements in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I can't quite get a handle on subsets. Are the following true or false?

$ \{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} $

$\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$

$\{x\} \subseteq \{x\}$
Is it a subset if it's perfectly equal?

$\{x\} \in \{x\}$
False, right? A true statement would be $\{x\} \in \{\{x\}\}$ right?

(edit: wow okay why are these not rendering with MathJaX)

Comment: the superset from the second problem can be written as just $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, since for example, $\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, so that is false, a set can not be a proper subset of itself. So 1 is correct, and 3 is correct since you have equality in your inclusion.

Comment: why are there two of the same elements in the second one?

Comment: 4 could be true in a set theory without Foundation! But probably you're being taught a founded theory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\emptyset{\varnothing}\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ — this is true.

About this: $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$,
this $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$ is not a set — you wrote something that contains two equal elements.
Notation $\{1, 1\}$ isn't quite good.
If you mean $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ you also have two possibilities: you may think about $\subset$ as a symbol for a relation "being a subset" — so the statement is true, or "being a proper subset" — and it is false.

$\{x\} \subseteq \{x\}$ — this symbol $\subseteq$ means "being a subset, proper or not", so it is true.

$\{x\} \in \{x\}$ — yeah, it's false. And yes, this $\{x\} \in \{\{x\}\}$ is true.

Comment: $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$ is a perfectly well-formed piece of notation for a set. It's just redundant. I'm guessing that's part of the "trick"; to make sure the reader isn't being fooled by the brackets and understands what $\subset$ means.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

When looking at proper subsets take away the first outer parenthesies and see if any elements are the same noting that $\{x\}\neq x$. $\subseteq$ means that they are a subset or equal is the set $\{x\}$ equal to itself? You are correct for the last one.